# Putting buttons to the left with javafx

Tags: java, javafx

With SceneBuilder a put one button to the right (`btnOne`) and other button with a image on top of the button to the left (`btnTwo`), like this:

```
|btnOne--------------btnTwo|
```

but when I open my application `btnTwo` don´t go all the way to the left, instead I get something like: `|btnOne----------btnTwo---|`

I have solve this kind of things with HBox but in this case, if I put the `btnTwo` inside a HBox I can´t put an image above the button.

How can I solve this?

This is my code

```
          <Pane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="800.0"  VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <HBox prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="863.0" spacing="20.0">
                     <children>
                        <Button fx:id="btnOne" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="132.0" styleClass="btn-success"  />
                     </children>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets left="10.0" top="5.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </HBox>
                  <Button fx:id="btnTwo" layoutX="870.0" layoutY="6.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="35.0" styleClass="btn-default" />
                  <ImageView fitHeight="24.0" fitWidth="24.0" layoutX="1013.0" layoutY="12.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../../../userData/ie.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>                 
               </children>
            </Pane>
```

Comment: It is not entirely clear where exactly you d like to depict an image.

If you just want to create Button with Icon pls take a look at
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/button.htm

You also could try to investigate GridPane to organize controls.
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "spacer" to occupy the empty space :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Region?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<Pane prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="800.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <HBox prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="800.0" spacing="20.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="btnOne" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="132.0" styleClass="btn-success" />
            <Region fx:id="spacer" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <Button fx:id="btnTwo" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="35.0" styleClass="btn-default" />                
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets left="10.0" top="5.0" />
         </padding>
      </HBox>
    </children>
</Pane>
```